# function to calculate ARC tangent in C#

Tags: c#, math

i need output for arc tangent and cotangent. i think the math.atan(value) is for cotangent
but not sure what to do with Arc tangent

my code
{
VALOR = Convert.ToDouble(TVALOR.Text);

```
        if (RBSENO.Checked)
            R = Math.Sin(VALOR);
        if (RBCOSENO.Checked)
            R = Math.Cos(VALOR);
        if (RBTANGENTE.Checked)
            R = Math.Tan(VALOR);
        if (RBCOTANGENTE.Checked)
            R = Math.Atan(VALOR);
        if (RBARCOTANGENTE.Checked)
            R = Math.
        if (RBLOGARITMO.Checked)
            R = Math.Log(VALOR);
        if (RBRAIZ.Checked)
            R = Math.Sqrt(VALOR);
        if (RBACOSENO.Checked)
            R = Math.Acos(VALOR);
        if (RBASENO.Checked)
            R = Math.Asin(VALOR);
        TR.Text = Convert.ToString(R);
    }
```

Comment: Trig is not my forte, but isn't it as easy as, Arctangent `Math.Atan()` and Cotangent `Math.Atan(1 / adjacent)` ?

Comment: "i think the `math.atan(value)` is for cotangent" - that's completely wrong. [Why haven't you read the documentation?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.atan?view=net-5.0) - it says right there: **"Returns the angle whose tangent is the specified number."** - the cotangent is just the reciprocal of tan: cotangent

Comment: This page demonstrates how to compute derived trig functions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/keywords/derived-math-functions

Comment: i my code i only have 1 variable, so based on what you guys are saying i would need at least 2 variables to calculate cotangent? @Dai if i would've known about this i would not have asked. i knoW im probably wrong, THATS WHY IM ASKING

Comment: This wasn't really a programming problem per-se, more just a research, comprehension and critical thinking task. There is not one person on earth who doesn't make mistakes or an expert at everything... As for the comment "*i my code i only have 1 variable, so based on what you guys are saying i would need at least 2 variables*" - the answer is no

Comment: i tried this Math.Atan(1 / adjacent) but it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
using System;
public class test
{
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            double arctan = Math.Atan(20.0);
            double cotangent = 1 / Math.Tan(10.0);
            System.Console.WriteLine("arctan:"+ arctan + " cotan:" + cotangent);
        }
}
```